# I cant seem to be able to display my images in the slider.(Processwire)But all my fields in the repeater are properly set

Tags: php, processwire

```
<section class="hero-slider style1">
  <div class="home-slider">
    <!-- Single Slider -->
    <?php
    foreach ($page->slider_repeater as $slider_repeater) {
      echo "<div class='single-slider' style='background-image:url('{$slider_repeater->images->url}{$slider_repeater->images}')'>";
      echo "<div class='container'>";
      echo "<div class='row'>";
      echo "<div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12'>";
      echo "<div class='welcome-text'>";
      echo "<div class='hero-text'>";
      echo "<h4>{$slider_repeater->texth4}</h4>";
      echo "<h1>{$slider_repeater->texth1}</h1>";
      echo "<div class='p-text'>";
      echo "<p>{$slider_repeater->textp}</p>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
  </div>
</section>
```

The section on background image seems to be the problem, all the other text is working well in the site but the images.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if your field is set to single-value or multi-value output. In the backup, go to Setup -> fields -> images and check the *Details* tab. Take note of the *Maximum files allowed* and *Formatted value* settings. Those will tell you whether your *images* field contains a single image or multiple images.

There's also multiple things going wrong inside your *background-image:url* function: `style='background-image:url('{$slider_repeater->images->url}{$slider_repeater->images}')'`

1. You're using single quotes (`'`) both to delimit the start and end of your HTML attribute value AND inside the `url` function, this might cause errors. Leave out the single quotes inside the `url` function.
2. What's the purpose of the second *{$slider_repeater->images}* call? Leave that out.

All that said, change your style parameter to one of the following and it should work:

```php
// if your images field is set to Single item, or Automatic with a limit of 1
style='background-image:url({$slider_repeater->images->url})'

// if your images field is set to Arry of items, or Automatic with a limit of 0 or >1
style='background-image:url({$slider_repeater->images->first->url})'
```